# NullPointerException at Timer

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I get this error. not on any device, just on some.
This is all the report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at eu.innovaapps.tpark.ro.MainSms$4$1$1.run(MainSms.java:444)
at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

and it comes from:

```
buton.setEnabled(false);

                        Timer buttonTimer = new Timer();
                        buttonTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        buton.setEnabled(true);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }, 5000);
```

When i press the button it gets disabled and after 5 seconds it gets enabled again.
Line 444 is `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {`.
I'd appreciate alot if you could help me solve this error.

EDIT:
I got the same problem as here:
[Scheduled Task in Fragment returns getActivity as null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579603/scheduled-task-in-fragment-returns-getactivity-as-null)

If the button in disabled, and i press the back button of the phone, i get this error which sends me at this part of the code. 
Is there a way i could stop the timer if the back button is pressed?

Comment: where in the code exactly do you get the npe??

Comment: I think that the npe is on getActivity() or buton.
This piece of code is written into onCreateView method of a fragment?

Comment: it is written in onStart method of a fragment

Comment: getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { this is line 444

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell what is the line number 444 in your code ?

**If line 444 is `buton.setEnabled(true);`** then can you modify the code to add Button buton = (Button) findViewById(R.id. just before `buton.setEnabled(true);` and then try out the same code.

**EDIT**

Dear Victor,

I have read your EDIT... I used to get such exception... To go around this, what I have done is that I declared and static variable in my Activity class...

```
public static sActivity = null;
```

and then in onCreate method of Activity I assigned the current activity to it...

```
sActivity = this;
```

and then used it in the code instead of getActivity()...

So for e.g. my Activity name is myActivity then your code in that case could changed to...

```
 @Override
 public void run() {
      getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 




  @Override
     public void run() {
          if (myActivity.sActivity != null) {
              myActivity.sActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
          .
          .
          .
          }
```

Let me know if you find any other better solution...

Comment: this is the npe line: getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

Answer (score -3):

```
Timer notificationtask = new Timer();
notificationtask.schedule(new TimerTask() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                            buton.setEnabled(true);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });

    }
}, 1000, 1000);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned upon on SO. Please explain *why* this answer should help and what you did. Also, please take the time to format your answers properly.